# Pumping lemma in PDA and CFL

Tags: automata, pushdown-automaton, pumping-lemma

I have an pumping lemma question I totally stuck on...

L = {w ∈ {a, b, c}∗ : na (w) < nb (w) < nc (w)}

is it CFL or not?

I quest it is not CFL because it is not enough to have one stack to remember al those conditions. You can remember that  na (w) < nb (w) or na (w)< nc (w),nb (w) < nc (w) but not na (w) < nb (w) < nc (w). In addition I though that if the language is a^pb^2pc^3p and than if I pumped  up |vy| for p times L is not CF however is it possible tu pump up for p times?

Or any idea for the solution?

Comment: is this a homework? it seems like a straightforward proof by contradiction

Comment: btw, I just found two similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095509 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Pumping lemma requires *every* string in **L** to stay in **L** after pumping. So, it is enough to get contradiction even for some specific form of strings in **L**.

a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>2p</sup>c<sup>3p</sup> is a nice example but I suggest to try a shorter one: a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>p+1</sup>c<sup>p+2</sup>.

The reasoning is almost the same as in the Wikipedia article: [Pumping lemma:Usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Usage_of_the_lemma). You will have the same five cases and it's quite straightforward to get contradiction in each one.